# Integrating Java Web App with SAML SSO

Tags: java, rest, single-sign-on, saml

I have a Restful Java Web application which is to be deployed to a number of different environments (outside of my control) which will be using a SAML 2.0 SSO solution.

My application (which I believe is the "service provider") needs to store state generated by the user, and uses internal business logic to work out which users are allowed to view or update other user's data.  In order for this to work we need to know who the user is, and what groups the user is part of.  But how do I get this information?

Ideally my web app will be SSO agnostic, and would look for some configurable key headers in the http requests to get this information e.g. a SAML token in a request which could be parsed, or perhaps some custom headers specific to my "service provider".

Many Thanks

Comment: Aren't session cookies generally used to authenticate users in RESTful SSO?

Comment: I would look into Spring Security or Apache Shiro, both can wrap web context to provide various authentication and user store mechanisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could run a reverse proxy in front of the Java web application to handle the SSO protocol part and relay user identity information to the application in HTTP headers; for SAML 2.0 there is mod_auth_mellon: https://github.com/UNINETT/mod_auth_mellon

Comment: Thanks Hans - you've pointed me in the right direction.  Using an agent of some kind should allow me to map between the token and HTTP headers.   There is a reference to this for OpenAM here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414460/how-to-implement-openam-sso-to-my-existing-web-applications

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, your application is the Service Provider and you will have an external Identity Provider (IdP) to authenticate to.

Basically you need to issue an Authentication Request to the IdP (via either front channel HTTP POST or back channel SOAP/whatever they support) and use the authenticationResponse from the IdP to make your decision on whether they are who they say they are. As a rule you should be able to get the subject principal (ie username) and any group memberships from the authnResponse however exactly how this works will depend on what the IdP is or isn't configured to do.

Before you do this you will need to exchange SAML metadata with the IdP (this is generally part of being registered as a SP with the IdP) which gives both parties things like the public X509 cert for signing and validating requests.

There's a good spring library for SAML SP support, http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle

Answer (score 0):

If this is done in Java and running on a webcontainer (Tomcat, JBoss, etc.), then the agent could be implemented as a web authentication (servlet) filter (add into web.xml). The user would be typically derived from the SAML Auth response's <saml:NameID> or from <saml:Attribute> matching the userid attribute (uid,email, etc.). This user should be validated against the web app's identity repository (could be LDAP, database, etc.) and corresponding groups computed. Instead of using arbitrary headers or custom representation for the authenticated user, consider using java *Principal* (for users and groups) in a *Subject*. 
The filter can then run the rest of the filter chain in a *Subject.doAs()*. That way, the *Subject* can be looked up any where in the downstream code using *Subject.getSubject()*.